# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Member.__format__

Tags: python, typeerror

```
    server = ctx.message.server
    msg = ""

    if server.id not in self.slowed_db:
        await self.bot.say(error("There isn't anyone in Slow Mode in this server."))
        return

    names = [server.get_member(x).name for x in self.slowed_db[server.id]]
    names_len = len(max(names, key=len))
    for key, value in self.slowed_db[server.id].items():
        try:
            member = server.get_member(key)
            msg += "{:<{names_len}} {}\n".format(member, value['seconds'], names_len=names_len)
        except AttributeError:  # User isn't in server
            continue
    if msg:
        await self.bot.say(box(msg, lang="css"))
    else:
        await self.bot.say(error("There isn't anyone in Slow Mode in this server."))
        return
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work? The error is on this line:

```
msg += "{:<{names_len}} {}\n".format(member, value['seconds'], names_len=names_len)
```

`names_len` prints just fine as an integer so I'm very confused.

Comment: I think you want to pass `member.name` there, not `member` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to pass `member.name` there, not `member` itself.